# mysql update days of login based on lastlogin

Tags: mysql, authentication

I have following structure in a mysql table:

```
-------------------------------------
| id | username | lastlogin  | days |
-----+----------+------------+-------
| 1  | user-xyz | 2013-04-29 | 0    |
-------------------------------------
```

The above 'lastlogin' column is date column and 'days' column is int(3) column.
What I want to do, while a user will login, lastlogin column will be updated everytime as usual. At the same time, the 'days' column will be incremented if the login date (when the user is logging in) is greater than the date of lastlogin column. If the user is logging in at the same day again, the days will be same (will not be updated).

What will be the mysql query in this case?

The query format will be something like this:

```
$logindate = date("Y-M-D",time());

UPDATE table
SET lastlogin=$logindate, days=days+1 if $logindate>lastlogin
WHERE usename=user-xyz
```

Thanks in advance if any help to build the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET days=days+IF($logindate=lastlogin, 0, 1), lastlogin=$logindate
WHERE username='xyz'
```

Note that `lastlogin=$logindate` has to appear after [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) otherwise DATEDIFF always returns 0 because lastlogin=$logindate acts first.

Comment: Thanks Vishy for your reply. But your code will not do the thing exactly. Suppose, date difference between 21 April 2013 and 30 April 2013 is 10 days. So, if a user login on 30 April 2013, it will put 10 in days column. But the user might not logged in everydays in between 21 and 30 April. He/she might have logged in 21, 23, 25, 27 & 30 April 2013, so he/she actually logged in 5days, but your code will put 10days. The solution is to increment the value of days column whenever the user log in. Thanks

Comment: @stockBoi Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Vishy, It may do the work, I will check and inform you whether it will work or not correctly.

Comment: No vishy, for any reason it is no working, it is showing following mysql error messages: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '21:19:41=lastlogin, 0, 1), lastlogin=2013-05-01 21:19:41 WHERE users='user-xyz'' at line 2

Comment: Enclose the $logindate inside single quotes. Sorry for missing it in my query - which I copied from MySQL console and edited :) In the end it should be something like this: `UPDATE may1
SET days=days+IF('2013-01-05'=lastlogin, 0, 1),
lastlogin='2013-01-05'
WHERE username='xyz'`